# Поиск значения в строке c++

Tags: c++, строки, кодировка

### Пытаюсь найти подстроку в строке

Есть файл `2.html`. В нем есть значение "Ваш IP". Считываю построчно и пытаюсь найти в строке необходимое значение.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    bool t = false;
    size_t temp;
    string str;
    char buf[2048];
    const char* substr = "Ваш IP";

    ifstream file;
    file.open("2.html");

    while (!file.eof()) {
        getline(file, str, '\n');

        ZeroMemory(buf, 2048);
        strcpy(buf, str.c_str());
        t = OemToAnsi(buf, buf);
        str = (string)buf;

        temp = str.find(substr);
        if (temp != string::npos)
            break;
    }
    file.close();
    cout << str << endl;

    Sleep(3000);
    return 0;
}
```

При выполнении цикла в отладчике видно, что из файла считываются каракули в тех строках, где есть русские буквы. Как я их только не пытался перевести. Не выходит. Поэтому и не ищет значение. Как решить эту задачу ?

> (файл 2.html получен скачиванием страницы http://2ip.ru)

`substr` переобъявлял через массив `char` и переводил в OEM. Не ищет

Comment: На сайте есть метатег: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` Что говорит о том что, исходные данные находятся в кодировке `UTF-8`.

Comment: Спасибо. Поищу как переводить

Comment: Проще будет просто спарсить нужное значение через id элемента на странице и взять его содержимое

Comment: @BogdanBida, Вы правы. Именно это я уже и сделал.